# Converter String encoded to byte

Tags: java, android, string, aes

Estou a user encriptação AES-GCM no meu servidor, e a desencriptar no meu android client.
Contudo estou a ter um problema na conversão.

Supomos que:

1- O texto encriptado gera o valor em bytes: `[B@541fe858`

2- Esse valo é embebido num `JSONObject` e enviado para o cliente.

3- O cliente recebe esse valor com:

```
  String cryptoJSON =  JSONencryptedresponseWS.getString("crypto");
```

Que resulta com o valor correcto de `[B@541fe858`.

4- Contudo depois esta String tem de ser convertida para bytes, para passar esse valor para a função de *decrypt*. O problema é que ao fazer os métodos `cryptoJSON.getBytes` ou usando o `base64.decode`, resulta num valor diferente do esperado (e.g `[B@f2f55b3`).

Alguém sabe como posso retirar o valor concreto que está na `String` para o formato byte, fazer uma conversão directa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1- O texto encriptado gera o valor em bytes: `[B@541fe858`

Errado. Isso daí não é o valor em encriptado. É apenas o resultado de chamar o método `toString()` em um array.

Por exemplo:

```
byte[] bytes = {(byte) 'a', (byte) 'b', (byte) 'c'};
System.out.println(bytes);
System.out.println(bytes.toString());
byte[] bytes2 = {(byte) 'a', (byte) 'b', (byte) 'c'};
System.out.println(bytes2);
```

Produz como saída:

```
[B@1540e19d
[B@1540e19d
[B@677327b6
```

[**Veja aqui no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/Jou3hT)

O que você deveria fazer é usar o [construtor de `String` que recebe um `byte[]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-) como parâmetro:

```
byte[] bytes = {(byte) 'a', (byte) 'b', (byte) 'c'};
String s = new String(bytes);
System.out.println(s);
```

Eis a saída:

```
abc
```

Todo o resto da sua pergunta está errada porque se baseia no fato de que o formato começando com `[B@` está correto, mas não está. Isso acontece porque arrays não sobreescrevem o método `toString()` da classe `Object`, que por padrão produz como resultado o nome binário da classe, seguido de um `'@'` e seguido do resultado do `hashCode()` em hexadecimal. O nome binário de `byte[]` é `[B`. O `hashCode()` de um array também é herdado de `Object` e derivado do endereço de memória do objeto.

Esse comportamento padrão do `toString()` herdado de `Object` é na maioria das vezes um comportamento inútil que produz um resultado sem qualquer serventia. Mesmo objetos com idêntico conteúdo mas em diferentes locais na memória gerarão resultados diferentes e igualmente inúteis no `toString()` (veja no primeiro código desta resposta que os dois arrays de idênticos conteúdos geram resultados diferentes no `toString()`). É isso que está acontecendo com você. Você deveria usar o [construtor adequado de `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-) para ter a codificação de `byte[]` correta.

Comment: "1- O texto encriptado gera o valor em bytes: [B@541fe858
Errado. Isso daí não é o valor em encriptado. "

Você amigo é que não leu bem. Concordo que isso é um metodo toString de um CRIPTOGRAMA (TEXTO ENCRIPTADO).

O seu primeiro exemplo ta muito bom e já o tenho implementado exactamente da mesma maneira. O  que eu preciso é do processo inverso! 

Exemplo: Recebo no meu android cliente

String jsonCryptograma=JSONencryptedresponseWS.getString("crypto")

Que produz o valor [B@1540e19d. Agora como converto o jsonCryptograma para bytes?

Comment: @rew1nd Que tal chamar o [método `getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--)?

Comment: @Vitor por favor lê a pergunta! 

 String crypto = [B@541fe858
 byte[] bt = crypto.getBytes();      = [B@f2f55b3

O que eu necessito é que o valor [B@541fe858 seja transformado para o formato byte sem alterações!